# Mongoose instance methods losing execution context

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
requiredAttr = {type: String, required: true},
employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        employeeNumber: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        firstName: requiredAttr,
        lastName: requiredAttr,
        image: requiredAttr
    },
    {
        timestamps: true //get createdAt, updatedAt fields
    });

employeeSchema.methods.writeThis = () => {

  console.log("doing writeThis");
  console.log(this);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

Always yields

```
doing writeThis
{} //would think I would see my employee properties here
```

then I test some basic context switching via node command line and find I can't do the following (like in the browser)

```
let test = { foo: "bar" };
let writeThis = () => { console.log(this); };
writeThis.apply(test); //or
writeThis.bind(test);
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function and Arrow syntax are not directly interchangeable:

```
let writeThisArrow = () => {
    console.log(this);
};
writeThisArrow.call({stuff: "things"});
// {}

function writeThisFunction() {
    console.log(this);
}
writeThisFunction.call({stuff: "things"});
// {stuff: "things"}
```

In function syntax, calling `this` references the context where it's called. In Arrow syntax, calling `this` references to the context where it's defined. In the case of your usage in mongoose, it's the actual `this` of the file itself. For example:

```
exports.stuff = "things";

let writeThisArrow = () => {
    console.log(this);
};
writeThisArrow.call();
// {stuff: "things"}
```

<s>"`this`" in arrow syntax is immutable,</s> You can't inject context using `bind()`, `call()`, or `apply()`. In your case, just switch back to standard function declaration and you'll be fine.

**EDIT**: I used the wrong wording. `this` is not *immutable* in arrow syntax, you just can't change the context through application. However, you *can* change it by editing the context where it was defined:

```
exports.stuff = "things";
let writeThisArrow = () => {
    console.log(this);
};
writeThisArrow.call();
// {stuff: "things"}

exports.otherStuff = "other things";
writeThisArrow.call();
// {stuff: "things", otherStuff: "other things"}
```